# Wildcard for terms in phrase - Lucene

Tags: lucene, wildcard

Google's query syntax allows to search phrases like "as * as a skyscraper" where the asterisk can match any term (or terms). Is there a way to achieve the same thing in Lucene? The proximity operator ~ could be of use but it is not what I exactly want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a SpanNearQuery. [Mark Miller's SpanQuery Blog Post](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/) explains how to use it, and the examples are similar to what you describe.

Comment: Perfect. SpanQuery is very expressive.